# Excel tables and user interface (Windows app)

Tags: c#, excel, database, algorithm, filter

it's about a project. I have different Excel Tabels. They contain different processes and how much energy/power is consumed.
I need to create a user interface where you can search for processes and see how much power is consumed in each process.
I thought I'd use C# and read the Excel tabels and try to represent them as a Windows form somehow.  Can it work like this ?
Do you have a better or simple idea? I am a beginner